# jsfiddle not working in IE8. It works in Firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

This is how jsfiddle looks in my IE8:

[image]

and the following js errors:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Timestamp: Mon, 8 Apr 2013 09:49:23 UTC


Message: Expected ':'
Line: 222
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://jsfiddle.net/js/jshint.js?TheBlackKeys


Message: Expected identifier
Line: 105
Char: 25
Code: 0
URI: http://jsfiddle.net/js/EditorCM.js?TheBlackKeys


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 24
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://jsfiddle.net/js/heyoffline.js?TheBlackKeys


Message: 'MooShellEditor' is undefined
Line: 91
Char: 7
Code: 0
URI: http://jsfiddle.net/


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 7326
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://jsfiddle.net/js/moo-clientcide-1.3.js?TheBlackKeys


Message: 'editor' is null or not an object
Line: 130
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://jsfiddle.net/js/Actions.js?TheBlackKeys
```

Comment: so, jsFiddle is not IE8 compatible? Throw a bugreport at them, not at us.

Comment: I can't test right now, but I don't think it's supported.

Comment: for those who already have a jsfiddle link and you just want to *test* it on IE8 you can just add `embedded/result` to the end of the link. You can also get this by clicking `Share`->`Share full screen result` from the fiddle in another browser

Answer (score 2):

jsFiddle isn't compatible with IE8.
For testing under unsupported browsers we do suggest to use "draft" feature: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#draft-page

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with you programming or whatever you are coding, is just a bad consideration from http://jsfiddle.net/ with crossbrowser compatibilty (in this case with IEv8)

Any way, if you really need to test in IE8, run this in the console:

```
document.getElementById('content').style.height = '800px';
```

Where '800px' fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with gmo.  I have issues using jsFiddle on IE8, and need to use Chrome instead.

There's also several open bug reports for jsFiddle on IE8 [Here](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/311) and [Here](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/108). To date they have not been resolved.